# How to select only that what matches all parameters in many-to-many

Tags: mysql

Need to get only the records that match all the specified conditions in many-to-many relationship.
Greatly simplified tables look like

```
Catalog     Catalog_Types           Types
   1            1  1                  1
   2            1  2                  2
   3            2  1                  3
                2  3                  4
                2  4
                3  1
                3  4
```

It easy to select from *Catalog* by 1 type, but i need select by 1 ore more, for example how to get from *Catalog* only those rows that have *Types* 1 **and** 2, so if it have 1 but haven't 2 it is not suitable.

I saw a similar question and the decision here, but for the SQL. There used except, i tried to replace it by equals on mySQL, but I do not know mySQL so well.

thank you in advance,
and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of query is called "set within set"

If you want to get catalog ids with two types (1 and 2) but may have other types

```
SELECT catalog_id
  FROM catalog_type
 WHERE type_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY catalog_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) = 2
```

if want to make sure you get catalog ids with **exactly two types** (e.g. 1 and 2)

```
SELECT catalog_id
  FROM catalog_type
GROUP BY catalog_id
HAVING SUM(type_id = 1) > 0
   AND SUM(type_id = 2) > 0
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) = 2;
```

if you want to get catalog ids which have **at least two of three types** (e.g. 1, 2, 4)

```
SELECT catalog_id
  FROM catalog_type
 WHERE type_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY catalog_id
HAVING (MAX(type_id = 1)
      + MAX(type_id = 2)
      + MAX(type_id = 4)) >= 2
```

Assuming that you have following in `catalog_type`

```
| CATALOG_ID | TYPE_ID |
------------------------
|          1 |       1 |
|          1 |       2 |
|          2 |       1 |
|          2 |       3 |
|          2 |       4 |
|          3 |       1 |
|          3 |       2 |
|          3 |       4 |
```

Sample output for above-mentioned queries:

```
    query 1        query 2         query 3

| CATALOG_ID |  | CATALOG_ID |  | CATALOG_ID |
--------------  --------------  --------------
|          1 |  |          1 |  |          1 |
|          3 |                  |          3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7f4a/3)** demo for all these queries. Take a look and see how results differ.

Comment: looks like exactly what i need) going to test that!